# Grouping expressions by associative equivalence for a single operation

Tags: expression-manipulation

I would like to group expressions under associative equivalence, but only for a specific operation used in the expression (not for other operations).

Say we have two binary operations A and B applicable to positive integers and producing positive integer outcomes (for instance + and x on the positive integers). Expressions of the following type can be formed

A(3,1), B(7,9), A(B(1,2),3), B(A(2,1),A(B(1,3),5)),  ...

The aim is to group such expressions according to equivalence under associative recombination of *one* of the operations. Say for operation A.

For instance (replacing arbitrary positive integers with an atom x for clarity):

A(B(x,x), A(x, A(x,x))) should be equivalent to 
A(A(A(B(x,x),x),x),x)

But no changes should be made to expressions using B in which associative recombinations could potentially be made.

For instance:

B(B(A(x,x),x), B(x, B(x,x))) should *not* be equivalent to 
B(B(B(B(A(x,x),x),x),x),x)

Are there commands in Mathematica that test expressions for associative equivalence for a particular, i.e. fixed choice of operation?

I don't wish to make the expressions literally equivalent to one another and collapse them to a single representative. I just wish to group them into say lists of equivalent expressions.

*ETA* I found a reference to ``Flatten" and am considering to use it as in:

Flatten[A[B[u, v], A[x, y]], Infinity, A]

I will leave the post up, and wonder whether I could just check for associative equivalence this way?

For instance via:

Flatten[A(B(x,x), A(x, A(x,x))), Infinity, A] == 
Flatten[A(A(A(B(x,x),x),x),x), Infinity, A]

Comment: does `SetAttributes[A, {Flat, Orderless}]` help at all?

Comment: I think that would make them equivalent, rather than group them by equivalence. I found a command ``Flatten". Not sure yet it will do the trick but I adjusted my post. Have to head off to work soon, but will revisit later today.

Comment: so `A` is _not_  associative but in grouping the list of expressions you want to process each expression _**as if**_  A is associative?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep A not associative, but group it as if it were.

Comment: Using Flatten[A (B (x, x), A (x, A (x, x))), Infinity, A] produces an error: Syntax: "(" cannot be followed by "B(x,x),A(x,A(x,x)))". Not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flatten` is a nice approach.

You can also do:

```
ClearAll[asIfAWereAssociative]
asIfAWereAssociative = Block[{a}, SetAttributes[a, Flat]; # /. A -> a] &;

expressions = {A[B[x, x], A[x, A[x, x]]], A[A[A[B[x, x], x], x], x]};
Equal @@ (asIfAWereAssociative /@ expressions)
```

> True

```
GatherBy[expressions, asIfAWereAssociative]
```

> {{A[B[x, x], A[x, A[x, x]]], A[A[A[B[x, x], x], x], x]}}

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[expressions, asIfAWereAssociative]
```

> {A[B[x, x], A[x, A[x, x]]]}

Comment: Thanks! Beautiful solution. I sort of gather what Block is meant to achieve here: a local interpretation of A as being associative. GatherBy then collects the copies that are the same under this local identification. There is so much to know about Mathematica and I struggle at times to find the right operations.I have the book, but wonder if there are other introductions available for the language that you might recommend?

Comment: Specifically introductions focused on expression manipulation.

Comment: Thank you @Mike for the accept (I would prefer your `Flatten` approach). I think you might be aware of [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) . I keep Leonid Shifrin, Stan Wagon and Sal Mangano's books handy.

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I think that Shifrin is exactly what I need. Nice travel literature for upcoming trip :)  I want to focus on the language first. I adapted your GatherBy approach to: GatherBy[expressions, Flatten[#, Infinity, A] &] which works as you suggest.

Comment: Is it possible to filter out atoms? Flatten gives a warning on those. For instance Flatten[3, Infinity, A] gives: Flatten::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[3,\[Infinity],A].   I want to add a test for AtomQ[#]. Something like: GatherBy[expressions, Flatten[#, Infinity, A] /; !AtomQ[#] &] This produces the same error though. ETA: never mind, got it: Flatten[# /; ! AtomQ[#], Infinity, A] &]

Comment: One problem remains:  GatherBy[{A[B[x, x], A[x, A[x, x]]], A[A[A[B[x, x], x], x], x], x}, 
 Flatten[# /; ! AtomQ[#], Infinity, A] &]  produces: {{A[B[x, x], A[x, A[x, x]]]}, {A[A[A[B[x, x], x], x], x]}, {x}} However, it should produce (as before): {{A[B[x, x], A[x, A[x, x]]], A[A[A[B[x, x], x], x], x]}, {x}}, i.e. the first two expressions should form part of the same sublist, not separate sublists. I only added the condition to check for atoms. I don't see why this condition would have that side effect?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer seems to be the following, expressions need to be compared using flatten, which detects associative equivalence for A based on supplying A as third argument of flatten and specifying Infinity to check at all levels (of bracket nesting)

Flatten[A[B[x, x], A[x, A[x, x]]], Infinity, A] == 
 Flatten[A[A[A[B[x, x], x], x], x], Infinity, A]

ETA: And based on kglr's suggestion:

GatherBy[expressions, Flatten[#, Infinity, A] &]

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simpler, but basically equivalent to the accepted answer is:

```
SetAttributes[a, Flat];
GatherBy[expressions, ReplaceAll[A->a]]
```

> {{A[B[x, x], A[x, A[x, x]]], A[A[A[B[x, x], x], x], x]}}